# Adding text to tricontourf

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to add a text caption to a plot that I make using tricontoruf using the below code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import pandas as pd

dx = {'1': 1, '2': -1, '3': -1, '4': 1, '5': 0}
x = pd.Series(data=dx, index=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

dy = {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': -1, '4': -1, '5': 0}
y = pd.Series(data=dy, index=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

dT = {'1': 10, '2': 20, '3': 30, '4': 40, '5': 50}
T = pd.Series(data=dT, index=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
CS=plt.tricontourf(x, y, T, cmap=cm.turbo, extend='neither', levels=np.arange(0,101,5))

plt.colorbar(CS)

plt.show()
```

Want to add something like `text(1, 1, "my text", fontsize=12)`. Can somebody help, please?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the OOP approach and then call [`Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) :

> `Axes.text`(x, y, s, fontdict=None, **kwargs)
>
> ***Add the text s to the Axes at location x, y** in data coordinates.*
>
> *Source* : [[matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.7.1/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L626-L692)]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

CS = ax.tricontourf(x, y, T, cmap=cm.turbo, extend='neither', levels=np.arange(0, 101, 5))

fig.colorbar(CS), ax.set_aspect('equal')

ax.text(0.5, 0.5, # X & Y coordinates
        s='StackOverflow', # <-- put your text here
        fontsize=12, # adjust the fontsize
        ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: **NB** : `(0,0)` and `(1,1)` correspond to the *lower-left* and *upper-right* corners respectively.